# Generic method which handles exception list with polly package

Tags: c#, list, .net-core, polly, retry-logic

I need to handle list of exception in generic way. I need to rewrite the  code in Polly style.

I have existing working code where custom generic exception handled:

```
readonly TimeSpan maxDelay;
readonly int initialRetryDelayInMilliseconds;
readonly double backoffFactor;
readonly int maxAttemptCount;
readonly string methodName;
readonly List<Exception> allowedExceptions;

public ExponentialBackoffService(string _methodName,int _initialRetryDelayInMilliseconds, TimeSpan _maxDelay, double _backoffFactor, int _maxAttemptCount, List<Exception> _allowedExceptions = null)
{
    initialRetryDelayInMilliseconds = _initialRetryDelayInMilliseconds;
    backoffFactor = _backoffFactor;
    maxAttemptCount = _maxAttemptCount;
    maxDelay = _maxDelay;
    methodName = _methodName;
    allowedExceptions = _allowedExceptions;
}

public virtual async Task<T> Do<T>(Func<Task<T>> task)
{
    TraceLogger.Log("ExponentialBackoffService", 0, "ExponentialBackoffService task do", true);

    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
    for (int attempted = 0; attempted < maxAttemptCount; attempted++)
    {
        var trace = TraceLog.GenerateTraceLog($"ExponentialBackoffService call started==>{attempted}");
        trace.Category = "ExponentialBackoffService";
        await Logger.WriteLogAsync(trace);

        try
        {
            if (attempted > 0)
            {
                TimeSpan retryDelayInMilliseconds = CalculateExponentialBackoff(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(initialRetryDelayInMilliseconds), attempted);
                await Task.Delay(retryDelayInMilliseconds);
                await Logger.WriteLogAsync(GenerateTrace(retryDelayInMilliseconds));
            }
            return await task();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (AllowAllException() || AllowSpecificExceptions(ex))
            {
                exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
            else { throw; }
        }
        finally
        {
            var trace1 = TraceLog.GenerateTraceLog($"ExponentialBackoffService call completed==>{attempted}");
            trace1.Category = "ExponentialBackoffService";
            await Logger.WriteLogAsync(trace1);
        }
    }
    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
 
public virtual bool AllowAllException()
{
    return  allowedExceptions == null || allowedExceptions?.Count() == 0;
}

public virtual bool AllowSpecificExceptions(Exception currentException)
{
    bool isCurrentExceptionAllowed = false;
    if(allowedExceptions?.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (Exception exception in allowedExceptions)
        {
            if(exception.GetType()== currentException.GetType())
            {
                isCurrentExceptionAllowed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isCurrentExceptionAllowed;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Need to rewrite the above code in polly style.

#### 1st question

```
var existingPolicy = Policy.WaitAndRetryAsyc(BackOff.DecorrletedJitterBackOffV2)
```

Here,need to define retry logic and logging for each retry; no exception definition

#### 2nd question

```
if(allowedExceptions?.Count() > 0)
{
    for(int i ;i<allowedExceptions.count();i++)
    {
        var dynamicPolicy=Policy.Handle<allowedExceptions[i].GetType>;//create dynamic policy for handle exception
        existingPolicy.WrapAsync(dynamicPolicy);//appending each exception as per exceptionList
    }
}
```

According to caller , will send a list of exception, those generic exceptions need to be added in the policy

And last execute

```
existingPolicy.executeAsync(task);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first try to reply to your second question.

Since your `allowedExceptions` is a `List<Exception>` that's why you can write this:

```cs
Policy.Handle<Exception>(ex => allowedExceptions.Contains(ex))
      ...
```

or simply just

```cs
Policy.Handle<Exception>(allowedExceptions.Contains)
      ...
```

In both cases you define a policy which should trigger only if an exception is thrown and that exception is one of the allowed exceptions.

---

Now let's focus on your first question.

In case of Polly V7 you can define a policy which should trigger either if a specific exception is thrown (`Handle<TEx>` / `HandleInner<TEx>`) or the result object is in a given state (`HandleResult<TResult>(Predicate p)`).

So, if you want to retry n times *unconditionally* then you can do the following workaround:

```cs
Policy.HandleResult<object?>(_ => true)
```

That means your to-be-decorated method needs to return either with a reference type instance or a null.

Or you can define the trigger for `bool`:

```cs
Policy.HandleResult<bool>(_ => true)
```

It's up to you which one do you prefer. It's a workaround because Polly V7 does not support unconditional triggering.